# How can I stop playing nether portal tag with a mooshroom?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> Minecraft 1.4.2
>
> The Pretty Scary Update!
>
> - Portals to the Nether can now transport items and mobs

I was trying to transport a mooshroom off a mushroom island using nether portals, but it has no momentum going through and is just sitting on the portal so whenever I hop in, it just hops out, any idea how I can get this thing to move?

Things I've tried:

- Hopping through with wheat in slot 1 to get it to follow - didn't accomplish anything as far as I can tell
- digging a step down 1 deep around the portal in the nether, in the hopes that I can push it off the portal when I come through.  This looks like it works *sometimes* but it still teleports out
- Hitting it with a weapon to make it move - I think I even have knockback on my current sword, but I can't actually make contact before it ports out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Tumblr](http://mcupdate.tumblr.com/post/35704186352/minecraft-1-4-4), this has been fixed for 1.4.4. If you haven't updated or can't due to the server your on, or are still having problems there may still be some solutions.

One thing you can try that I've seen having at least limited success, is dig a pit around the portal in the nether, such that it would be impossible for the animal to jump back in.  It looks like you may have tried this already, but I don't think it was deep enough (at least 2 blocks down from the edge of the portal).

If this is on a server, another option to at least try (I have no evidence that it'll work) is to have another player waiting on the other side with wheat (or another appropriate luring agent) so that the animal is lured away from the portal as soon as you teleport them.

Comment: @DKnight which part of this solution worked for you?

Comment: @SadlyNot I updated to the new version, the mooshroom was glitchy in the nether, but I did manage to push it into a minecart and move it to and thru the exit potal I wanted